# Android application to take pictures with good autofocus feature

Tags: android, camera

The autofocus feature of the default camera application on the Samsung S3 is often bad: pictures are blurry, typically when taking a picture of some text printed on paper.

I'm looking for an Android application (free if possible) that can take pictures and whose autofocus is better (i.e. fewer blurry pictures) than the default camera application.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [Camera Zoom FX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom). This software is packed with powerful features... It's premium though..

[image]

[image]

**Features** *(Pretty Long)*

**POWERFUL CAMERA**

- Optical / digital zoom (pinch to zoom up to 6x)
- Fastest camera on Android - fast action shot up to 20 shots per second
- Best Photo Mode! take up to 50 shots in burst mode, and let Camera ZOOM FX decide the best, or choose for yourself!
- Front facing camera - perfect for selfies
- Customization of ALL hardware buttons - e.g. volume buttons to control zoom, trackball to snap shot...
- Live previews of some effects, e.g. frames, buddies
- Silent camera (if device supports)
- Tweak hardware options: autofocus, whitebalance, nightshot...
- Settings for iso, focus metering, brightness, exposure, contrast, saturation, sharpness (based on device)
- Upload photo to Facebook, Twitter, Flickr, WhatsApp, etc.
- Flash (if avail)
- Customizable grid overlays
- Horizon level indicator

---

**MULTIPLE SHOOTING MODES**

- Stable Shot
- Timer
- Voice Activated: take a picture by clapping, shouting...
- Burst Mode
- Collage
- Time Lapse

---

**POST PROCESSING**

- Combine effects using non-destructive editing
- Process at full camera resolution (up to 8mp if avail)
- 10 ready made presets: Diana, Retro, Holga 35mm, Toy Camera...
- 20 Color FX: vintage, lomo, cinematic, funky, pencil...
- 15 Frames: thin, rounded, lens, polaroid, filmreel...
- 6 Vignette Surrounds: heavy, invert, spotlight...
- 12 Distort FX: fisheye (like fxcamera), mosaic, twirl...
- 9 Mirror FX
- 3 Tilt-shift FX
- 3 Textures, 5 Light Leaks, 5 Bokeh FX
- Crop to any size of your choice: 3x8, square, instant, 6x4...
- Digi composites (photoshop style overlays)
- Props and famous 'buddies' in your pictures (move and resize!)
- Create stunning collages: e.g. 2x2 passport style selfie combination shots
- Random effects

---

**OTHER FEATURES**

- Fullscreen shutter: click anywhere on screen to shoot!
- Animated shutter effect
- Support geotag / exif tags
- Select sdcard folder to save photos (incl external sd)
- Auto save shots
- Win $100 in Instagram style photo contest
- Pro scene modes, e.g. nightshot, beach (Droid only)
- View last shot in picture gallery
- Use as default camera
- Rotate / crop photos
- Widescreen lens / capture (if device supports)
- Support from Android 1.6 through to Android 4.4 (kitkat incl tablets)
- Switch to video
- ICS, JB, Holo style UI-